# Can I still compile without saving first?

Tags: texshop

I just upgraded my LaTeX package. Previously, if I were to make a change in the document and subsequently hit "typeset," the change would automatically be reflected in the preview, and the document would save <strike>simultaneously</strike> automatically with compiling. However, this seems to be different with the upgrade. If I make a change in the document and hit "typeset," the change does not show up in the preview unless I first save the document manually. Is there a way to revert to the previous way of doing things, so that I don't have to manually save before compiling?

If it helps, I am working on a Mac, and I upgraded from Version 2.43 to Version 2.45 of TeXShop.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the document is saved before typesetting, although I a still on v2.43 TeXShop.

Comment: It may be saved just before typesetting on v2.43, but, at least for me, it did so automatically. Is there a preference or something that controls this feature?

Comment: I'm on 10.8.2, updated from 10.6.8, and I have the same problem of Nick. Furthermore, if I got an error compiling the latex file and I hit "Go to error" it opens a new file instead of the compiled latex file with the error. Could these problems related to the update of the system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced in 2.45. Version 2.46 has now been released to fix it:

From the update window in TeXShop:

> TeXShop 2.45 introduced a bug;  users had to save the source file
>   before typesetting. TeXShop 2.46 fixes that inadvertent bug and
>   returns to the standard TeXShop behavior.

So the solution is to check for updates in TeXShop again and install the new version.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I just installed 2.46, and it returned to standard behavior as promised.

Comment: I have the same problem with version 3.11 now, under OSX 10.7.5. I couldn't get changes to happen when I typeset. A clue was after I tried, and then decided to quit, it would ask if I wanted to save changes. Finding this posting convinced me to save first, then typeset, and it works if I do that, and only if I save, then typeset. I did a COMPLETE reinstall of MacTeX 2012, having trashed every trace of everything relating to the TeXlive installation, and all supporting apps, etc. The behavior came right back. The "save before you typeset" works.