# Does TexShop automatically saves when you Typeset?

Tags: texshop

I always seem to compile the code but forget to save. Albeit I do save every now and then, but I want to know if it automatically saves when I compile the code, just incase my laptop hangs or something happens that might make me lose my work in the future.

Comment: I don't use TexShop, but it will surely save before compiling. TexShop itself doesn't do the compilation: it passes the whole `.tex` file off to pdflatex (or whichever compiler you are using). In order to do that it has to write the latest changes to the file.

Comment: The latest TeXShop version supports the auto-save features of OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It calls an external program to typeset, so it must save the file first.  Mac OS always gives a visual indication if the file has unsaved changes: the red "close window" button is blocked out.  You will notice that the button clears whenever you typeset.

([Version 2.45 had a bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57695/can-i-still-compile-without-saving-first?rq=1) where it did not automatically save when typesetting.  However, you would surely notice this, since changes would not appear in the output until you saved the file.)